# Missing data for geojson

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api, geojsonio

I made the following query in [overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/)

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “amenity=hospital”
  node["amenity"="hospital"]({{bbox}});
  way["amenity"="hospital"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="hospital"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out center;
>;
```

but unfortunately i do not get all the nodes displayed into [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/#map=8/37.313/21.984) from extracted geojson data (overpass-turbo).

Any idea that could help me to get all data?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like http://geojson.io does show *[nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node)* but not *polygons* (= OSM *[ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way)*). This could be a limitation of http://geojson.io or of the overpass turbo export, I'm not really familiar with the GeoJSON file format.

You can tell overpass to convert ways to nodes with the [geometry attribute](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Geometry_attributes) `out center;`. Try the following query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “amenity=hospital”
  node["amenity"="hospital"]({{bbox}});
  way["amenity"="hospital"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="hospital"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out center;
>;
```